# JavaScript RegExp Not Targeting all Instances of String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

My regular expression won't return all instances of `<li>.+<\/li>` found in textarea.

I Googled, and tried `/g`, but doesn't work.

**Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/8/).**

This is my `function(){...}`:

```
function doIt() {

    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var olPatt = /<ol>\s*(?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+<\/ol>/,
        ol = input.value.match(olPatt),
        olLi = ol.toString().match(/<li>/g), // MATCH ALL <li> with /g
        olLiB = ol.toString().match(/<\/li>/g); // MATCH ALL </li> with /g
    var i = 1; // start with 1

    input.value = input.value.replace(/<ol>/, "").replace(/<\/ol>/, "").replace(/\s*/, ""); // remove ol tags

    input.value = input.value.replace(olLi, function() {return i++ + "." + " ";}).replace(olLiB, " ");
    // should replace ALL <li> found in <ol> with number starting with 1 </li>        

}
```

If you're given this:

```
<ol>
<li>Hello world! :)</li> 
<li>Hello how are you</li> 
<li>good</li>
</ol>
```

It returns this: (incorrect)

```
1. Hello world! :)  
<li>Hello how are you</li> 
<li>good</li>
```

But, I want this: (correct)

```
1. Hello world! :)  
2. Hello how are you
3. good
```

Comment: I believe you just need to add 'g' to the end for a global search. So like this: input.value.replace(/<ol>/g, "")

Comment: Also, `{1}` is redundant, and you should consider using an HTML parser (like the one that’s built into browsers).

Comment: @false It may be unnecessary, but it's easier to read!

Comment: `<ol>{1}` is easier to read than `<ol>`?

Comment: @false Yes, because it tells me how many to look for.  I'm a beginner, just my preference.  If that syntax is malpractice, I won't use it!

Comment: `/g` should work, but you said that it didn't work for you. Can you show that version of your code, so we can help you understand where you went wrong?

Comment: @Matthew Then why don't you use it consistently? You should also have `{1}` after `<li>` and `</li>`.

Comment: @Matthew: I would definitely recommend against it; it’s misleading, because the `{1}` only applies to the `>`. If you changed it to `2` later, it would match `<ol>>`, not `<ol><ol>`.

Comment: @Barmar [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/9/) it is (lines `8` and `9`).  It breaks everything lol.  I think the problem is, the .toString(); or something isn't being defined.

Comment: Please put it in the question, not a link in the comments.

Comment: When you use `/g` with `.match()` it returns an array of all the matches. You need to loop over all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/10/

You need to add the global modifier at the point where you do the actual replacing.

In this case it's in this line:

```
input.value = input.value.replace(olLi, function() {return i++ + "." + " ";}).replace(olLiB, " ");
```

Because you're specifying the regex pattern from a variable, you need to use the RegExp constructor and pass the global modifier as the second argument. The fiddle demonstrates this.

```
new RegExp(olLi, 'g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
input.value = input.value.replace(olLi, function () {
    return i++ + "." + " ";
}).replace(olLiB, " ");
```

`olLi` and `olLiB` are already matches on `ol.toString()`. Just keep them as regular expressions, or perform the replacement in another callback (this seems the most correct):

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/<ol>\s*((?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+)<\/ol>/g,
    function (list, listItems) {
        return listItems.replace(/<li>/g, function () {
            return i++ + '. ';
        }).replace(/<\/li>/g, '');
    });
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/11/)

Comment: Thank you, this works great!  I have a question; where is the `list` parameter?  Is it just there as a placeholder?  The first parameter in `function (list, listItems) {...}`

Comment: @Matthew: Yep! It contains the entire match; `listItems` is the parenthesized subexpression, i.e. the same thing but minus the `<ol>` and `</ol>`.